# Match Table Header To String inside LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi there I have a database of users who are able to receive emails for specific servers.

Table Ex:

```
UserName     Server1     Server2      Server3
Jane.Doe      True        False        True
```

Let me explain what exactly is happening, so I set a true or false to the server if they can receive emails or not for specific server.

Now a user submits a log and they pick a server they are reporting to. The Admins of that server will get an email.

However I don't want to hard code in (My boss got mad at me):

Example:

```
if (logSubmission.curServer == "Server1")
{

    email = db.Users.Where(m => m.Server1 == true).Select(m => m.UserName).ToList();                    
}
```

So what I thought I could do is:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> server = db.servers.Select(m => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = m.server1,
                Text = m.server1


            });    

            string serverFixed = "";

            foreach (var item in server)
            {
                if (item.Text == logSubmission.curServer)
                {
                    serverFixed = item.Text;
                    serverFixed = serverFixed.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

                }

            }
```

I had a table called servers which holds all the servers.
So I call that and create a list of SelectListItem.

I take the Text of the server and match it with what the current server we are looking at.

Once That is done I had to remove spaces because some servers were like this: "Server 2"

And since my User Table Has it as "Sever2" I needed to remove spaces to match it.

Now I need to find a way to get that variable serverFixed into a similar look as:

```
email = db.Users.Where(m => m.Server1 == true).Select(m => m.UserName).ToList();
```

I feel like if I can change the .Where to somehow match the serverFixed I could do it.

Any ideas what I could do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Table is already hard coded. I'm not sure if that was a good decision to use several fields for servers instead of one foreign key field to a catalogue table with all servers. But maybe you had some reasons for it. I believe it's impossible to use some kind of variable for a field in LINQ. So I would propose to create an enum with all servers like

```
public enum ServerEnum {server1, server2, ...}
```

and than you can use it to identify your servers:

```
switch(logSubmission.curServer)
{       
   case (ServerEnum.Server.ToString()):
     email = db.Users.Where(m => m.Server1 == true).Select(m => m.UserName).ToList();                    
     break;
...
}
```

But anyway if you could change a structure of your tables that would be a better decision.